# Ionic local notifications on click not working when the app is closed in ios devices

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic4

I’m using local notifications native plugin on my ionic 4
 project (latest version), but when I click on notification and my app is closed the click event is not triggered. It works when app is in background or foreground in ios device.
I use local notifications inside a provider and my on click code is inside its constructor but when app is closed it's not working. I’ve tried to write code inside platform ready in app/app.component.ts but this approach does not work. This is my code:

```js
this.platform.ready().then((readySource) => {
           this.localNotifications.on('click').subscribe(noti)=> { 
                                           alert("ok");
                });
        });
```

Comment: try to add platform.ready function in home page (rootPage)

Comment: but not working

Comment: @AnandhSp I have the same issue. I have tried to call it inside platform ready in home.ts constructor. But still no success.

I have IOS 12 in my iPad device. This woks pefectly when Ionic app is running in background.

Is it something related to event lifecycle.
https://blog.ionicframework.com/navigating-lifecycle-events/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I have tried to call it inside platform ready in home.ts constructor. But still no success. I have IOS 12 in my iPad device. This works perfectly when Ionic app is running in background.
But it does not work when App is killed and not opened.

Is it something related to event life-cycle?
https://blog.ionicframework.com/navigating-lifecycle-events/